# Where to put subscription code for ASP.NET Core Web API application so that it's won't block further execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have below code which I put into my ASP.NET Core Web API startup, it's stuck here only and further all processing hangs.

Where to put such kind of subscription code? Background service? Or anything else?

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    var client = new DaprClientBuilder().Build();

    // Subscribe for configuration changes
    SubscribeConfigurationResponse subscribe = await client.SubscribeConfiguration("redisconfigstore", new List<string>() { "myKey" });

    // Print configuration changes
    await foreach (var items in subscribe.Source)
    {
        var cfg = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(items);
        Console.WriteLine("Configuration update " + cfg);
    }
}
```

Comment: check on your `async` method that came from another assembly (class project or `dll`) and see if they missed `ConfigureAwait(false)`.